# WPF Linq to SQL Returning a Custom Object with Data Binding to DataGrid C# MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, linq-to-sql, data-binding, mvvm

I am trying to make the jump from WinForms to WPF and I'm trying to learn the correct way. I want to use a correct MVVM model. This is my first WPF project ever and I am having trouble with databinding with a linq result. I am aware that I could do this very easily in the code behind or even not use a custom object and return entire table form the linq query to the datagrid while still using a separate class. But I would like to stick to this format. I don't want to use a datatable.

Assume that I have a dbml with a "Job" table. I want to select columns "Job" (Linq seems to automatically rename this column to Job1), "Customer", and "Order_Date".

Here is my code:

```
namespace Custom_Teplate.Model
{
    public class LINQResult 
    {
        public System.String JobNum
        { get; set; }
        public System.String CustomerName
        { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime Order_Date
        {get; set; }

        public static LINQResult Create()
        {
            DataDataContext dc = new DataDataContext();
            dynamic query = (from ddd in dc.Jobs
                             where (ddd.Status == "Active")
                             select new LINQResult
                             {
                                 JobNum = ddd.Job1,
                                 CustomerName = ddd.Customer,
                                 Order_Date = ddd.Order_Date,   
                             });
           return query;
        }
    }
}
```

I add the namespace to my XMAL:

```
xmlns:c="clr-namespace:Custom_Teplate.Model"
<Window.Resources>
    <c:LINQResult x:Key="ResultListData" />
</Window.Resources>
```

and set the itemssource as follows:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ResultListData}}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's not really how I would do this. Your first mistake is that although you have added an instance of your `LINQResult` class into the `Resources` section, it has no data in it because you never call the `Create` method. This is how I would achieve this:

I access the database using `Linq2SQL` and fill custom data types like your example, but here's the difference... I have a view model class for *each* view. In the view model classes, I have *all* the properties that I want to display in the UI, whether they are collections or singular items. The view model classes implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface (this is essential) through a base class.

I have `DataTemplate`s set up in `App.xaml` that link the various view models to views and then I can display a view in the UI like this:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding ViewModel}" />
```

In the view model constructor, I call the database and fill the collection(s) and set the properties. In your example, you *seem* to be creating a `Linq` query that would return multiple items (`IEnumerable<LINQResult>`), but you're trying to return just one of these items from your `Create` method.

I would normally extend the `ObservableCollection<T>` class for each of my collection classes, so if I were you, I would create this:

```
public class LinqResults : ObservableCollection<LinqResult> 
{
    public LinqResults(IEnumerable<LinqResult> linqResults) : base(linqResults) { }
}
```

I would then change your query method to something like this:

```
public static LinqResults Create()
{
    DataDataContext dc = new DataDataContext();
    LinqResults linqResults = new LinqResults(
        from job in dc.Jobs
        where job.Status == "Active"
        select new LinqResult
        {
            JobNum = job.Job1,
            CustomerName = job.Customer,
            Order_Date = job.Order_Date,
        });
    return linqResults;
}
```

Then in a view model, I would add a collection property of type `LinqResults` and 'plug it in' to the INotifyPropertyChanged` interface:

```
public LinqResults LinqResults 
{
    get { return linqResults; }
    set { linqResults = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("LinqResults"); }
}
```

Finally, bind to the collection in a view and define a `DataTemplate` for your data type (remembering to define an XML namespace to access it):

```
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding LinqResults}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type YourXmlNamespace:LinqResult}">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding JobNum}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding CustomerName}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Order_Date}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Please take a look at Josh Smith's [WPF Apps With The Model-View-ViewModel Design Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) article for more information on MVVM.

Comment: Hey Sheridan, would your `LinqResults` constructor not be better off calling `: base(linqResults)`? The results will be the same, just less code

Comment: @Lukazoid, my actual base collection class that extends `ObservableCollection<T>` does pass `IEnumerable`s to the base class constructor, but I copied this constructor code from an upper level base class that added handlers to each item. You are right though, after removing the handler code, I could just have called the base constructor... I'll update the answer accordingly. Hope you're well, old friend. :)